# WCF Data Services how to create simple service methods

Tags: c#, .net, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a `WCF Data service` which uses the reflection provider to expose a data context. Now I need to implement some simple service methods (There are all actions. They don't have return values). I did some research with Google and also found a lot of posts.
But I never found something like an default implementation for the `IDataServiceActionProvider` which for example works with attributes or something like this.

Now the question:
Do I really need to implement the `IDataServiceActionProvider` by my own or is there something like `ReflectionDataServiceActionProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not answer you want to hear, but I'm not aware of a default implementation of IDataServiceActionProvider.

You might want to take a look into creating your OData service using Web API instead of WCF Data Services; from my understanding, creating actions is much easier with Web API.

Some quick sample code taken from [Alex's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/11/02/odata-in-webapi-microsoft-asp-net-web-api-odata-0-2-0-alpha-release.aspx?Redirected=true) to demonstrate the simplicity:

```
ActionConfiguration pullWheelie = modelBuilder.Entity<Motorcycle>().Action(“PullWheelie”); 
pullWheelie.Parameter<int>(“ForSeconds”); 
pullWheelie.Returns<bool>();
```

Alternatively, instead of creating an OData action, you could use WCF Data Services to create a "Service Operation" which is somewhat of a legacy actions/functions capability of OData. It's pretty easy to create one of these with WCF Data Services, but be aware that they'll be disappearing completely in OData v4.  To create a service operation, you just need to create a method in your data source and annotate it with the `WebGet` or `WebInvoke` attribute. Once you configure the permissions for accessing the method in `InitializeService`, your method will be invokable by clients. For details, see [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).